# Camera Bag Recommendation: is the Case Logic SLRC-205 suitable for all my gear?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, camera-bag

At present, I only have the option to buy a camera bag is online, so I am not able to try out different bags.  I have narrowed down my choices to the Case Logic SLRC-205 sling bag, because it seems to suit my requirements.

What I would like to carry in this bag is a Nikon D7000, 3 lenses (18-105mm, 70-300mm, 50mm), charger and cord, and if possible a flash too.

Not sure if I am asking for too much. Would appreciate some comments about the quality of this product and easy accessibility to my gear.

And I am open to other similar options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this bag for my D7100, an extra battery and 3 lenses, a 10-24mm, 35mm and a 70-200mm...

Technically they all fit in the bag, though i wish the bag would hold lenses differently rather than loose in a compartment... When i use this bag i only carry one extra lens with me (usually the 70-200) and keep my other lens on the camera. The good thing about this bag is the sling style, easy to carry and move to the front to get quick access to the camera. I plan on using this bag when travelling overseas to carry water and passport and stuff since it has plenty of pockets that are sealed but still accessible.

So in short to answer your question... Yes, i think everything *will fit* but you wont feel secure with the way the lenses are loose, personally if i were very active with all my stuff in this bag, i would worry about the lenses getting broken (hitting each other).

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Yea I have already bought this bag and liking it a lot. Due to its ease of use. especially a small pocket for lens cap and its build quality. Just one thing I dint like about it that it comes without a rain cover.

Answer (score 1):

According to Amazon, the Case Logic SLRC-205 sling bag fits:

> Sling holds most SLR camera bodies up to 7.9" x 7.3" x 7.9" with
>   attached lens, an additional lens and accessories.

According to B&H, the Nikon D7000:

> Dimensions (WxHxD)    5.2 x 4.1 x 3"

Based on that I would say that your camera and a lens with a length less then 4.9" would fit, along with one other additional lens. I would assume fitting 2 additional lenses, a charger, and a flash is going to be pushing the limit. You may fit it but it probably is going to stretch out the material or fit poorly in use.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased this bag because I was looking for a functional single strap sling bag that would allow me access to my Canon 40d easily and on the go. I got to go to Paris, FR on a biz trip and really hated the bag that I had. Most of the bags I've seen for traveling are either way too big for the type of shooting I do or just plain ugly and scream out "CAMERA BAG!!!" Not only does this bag look good, it was EXTREMELY functional. With a quick slide around the body you could get into the camera compartment easily and it has enough storage for my needs. I carried the camera with a 28-135mm attached (I think you could use up to a 70-300 if you wanted although it might be a bit tight), an 18-55mm in the upper compartment, along with a spare flash card, my usb cable, wall charger and a French phrase book (pocket sized)it packed well. The construction of the bag seems rugged enough (I plan to use it for hiking as well) and the padding and hammock system seem very good at protecting the camera. I have recommended this bag to several family members and I intend to order 3 more to give as gifts :-) No, I don't work for Case Logic, but when I find something of good quality that functions as advertised, I do think it's important to share that info. I don't think you'll be disappointed with this bag particularly for lots of walking and site seeing. As long as you're not some kind of pro who has to have more than 2 lenses and all kinds of gadgets you should be good to go. There is a flap on the outside to carry a tripod around and I do believe it would work, as I put my umbrella in it to see how that would go...no problems. Nice job Case Logic :-)